# Typesafe method for retrieving data of unknown type through interface

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism, c++14

***TL;DR version:***

I am designing a class in C++14 to be generic. Below I describe a design problem, and I would be grateful for a solution to implement what I'm trying, or a suggestion for a redesign.

Say the class I'm designing is called `Algo`. Its constructor is passed a `unique_ptr` to a type, say `Business`, which implements an interface (i.e., inherits from a pure virtual class) and does most of the serious work.

I want an object of type `Algo` to be able to return a pointer (or even a copy) of a data member from the `Business` object that it owns. But it can't know the type that `Business` will want to return. I expect the owner of `Algo` to know what will come out based on what `Business` he passed in.

In my C days, I would blow off the type system by passing around void* and casting as needed. But that sort of thing now wreaks to me.

***More detail:***

So, a sort of pseudo-C++14 implementation of the above situation might look like:

```
// perhaps a template here?
class AbstractBusiness {
  . . .
 public:
  ?unknownType? result();
};

class Algo {
  //Could be public if needbe.
  unique_ptr<AbstractBusiness> concreteBusiness_;

 public:
  Algo(std::unique_ptr<AbstractBusiness> concreteBusiness);
  auto result() {return concreteBusiness_.result();}
};

class Business : public AbstractBusiness {
  . . .
 public:
  std::valarray<float> data_;
  std::valarray<float> result() {return data_;}
};

:::

auto b = std::unique_ptr<AbstractBusiness>{std::move(new Business())};
Algo a(std::move(b));
auto myResult = a.result();
```

In this example, myResult will be a `std::valarray<float>`, but I don't want `Algo` or the `AbstractBusiness` interface to have to know that! The creator of `b` and `a` should be in charge of knowing what should come out of `a.result()`.

If I am taking a wrong turn in this design, don't hesitate to let me know. I'm a bit green at this point and very open to suggestions.

***I've tried...***
I obviously can't use auto for a virtual method, nor have a template in a virtual class. These are the only things that stood out.

I'm playing with the idea of making a container interface for whatever `Business.result()` returns, and just passing pointers to abstract type up to `Algo.result()`. But I'm starting to feel like there may be a better way, so I'm on here begging for suggestions.

Comment: Can all possible result types share some common ancestor class?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek Yeah, I mention at the bottom of the question that I'm considering creating an abstract sort of container and passing pointers to abstract type up from `concreteBusiness` through to `Algo.return()`. Is that what you're suggesting, or have I missunderstood?

Comment: Actually not. Even if you do - what `Algo` can return is only some `AbstractData` which requires another casting. This not much different than `void*`. Considering `Algo` is obviously unaware what data returned by `Business` *means* - therefore it makes no use of it. Does it really need to take part in returning the result? The caller knows exactly the exact type of data used in particular `AbstractBusiness`'s descendant - so why not simply ask this descendant?

Comment: @KubaWyrostek You may well be right---I may be guilty of trying too hard to protect `concreteBusiness`. I was trying to keep it private, but maybe I don't need to, and I'm just trying too hard for the sake of a 'getter' method. I should also say that `a.concreteBusiness->data_` is a bit ugly, but not a deal breaker.

Comment: `a.concreteBusiness->data_` won't work since you still don't know the type of `concreteBusiness` here. Only outermost caller is aware of the type.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek :0 You're right. I got a bit ahead of myself. So what exactly do you suggest?

Comment: In this line: `auto b = std::unique_ptr<AbstractBusiness>{std::move(new Business())};` you are losing information about actual type of `AbstractBusiness` involved. But if you keep a reference to `new Business()` compiler is then perfectly aware that `_data` in this reference is of type `std::valarray<float>`.

Comment: Have you considered [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/any.html) ? Similar to `std::function`, it only allows you to retrieve the underlying data if you know the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't actually described a design problem. You've described some
implementation choices that you've gone with and a roadblock you've
run into, but we don't know the reasons for the choices.

You tell us that `Algo` takes ownership of a business via a pointer to a
polymorphic interface `AbstractBusiness` and must provide a getter for
that business's data, though it doesn't know the concrete type of that
data (because it doesn't know the concrete type of the business).

Neither of these questions have evident answers:-

1. Why should `Algo` acquire a business via a polymorphic interface?
2. Why should `Algo` provide a getter for the data of its business?

But deciding it must be so leads to the roadblock.

**The polymorphic pothole and how to get out it**

Q1. leads us to wonder what is the motivation for `AbstractBusiness`? Platitudinously, it's safe to say you want it to provide a uniform interface for manipulating and querying all sorts of businesses of concrete types that may be determined at runtime.

To be fully fit for that purpose, `AbstractBusiness` will encapsulate a necessary and sufficient interface for discharging all of the operations and queries on concrete businesses that applications (including but not limited to your own) can reasonably be expected to need. Call that Plan A. What you have discovered is that *it isn't fully fit for Plan A*. If the application needs at times to manipulate or query "the data" of a business that is represented to it via an `AbstractBusiness`, then the `AbstractBusiness` interface needs to provide polymorphic methods to discharge all of those manipulations and queries, and each concrete business class needs to implement them appropriately for the type of data it contains.

Where your `AbstractBusiness` has the problematic:

```
?unknownType? result();
```

you need to code virtual methods that address all of the convincing answers to the question: *What might an application want to know about the notional* `result()` *, or do to it?*

In this light, the suggestion that has been canvassed to introduce another polymorphic interface, `AbstractData`, ancestral to all of the concrete `data` types of all the concrete businesses, may be viewed as a suggestion to compensate for the necessary methods that are missing from `AbstractBusiness` by separately encapsulating them in a rescue abstraction. Better to finish the unfinished `AbstractBusiness`.

This is all good and scriptural perhaps, but maybe what has actually stopped you from finishing `AbstractBusiness` already is the perception that the data of `BusinessX` can be *essentially* different from that of `BusinessY`, so that it is impossible to devise a single set of polymorphic methods that is necessary and sufficient to manage both.

If this is the case, it tells you that businesses *cannot* all be managed through a single abstract interface. `AbstractBusiness` can't be fully fit for that purpose and, if it has a role, its role can only be to manage polymorphic objects that represent more specialized abstractions, `BusinessTypeX`, `BusinessTypeY`, etc., within each of which the variety, if any, of concrete types *can* be accommodated by a single polymorphic interface.

`AbstractBusiness` will then present only the interface that is shared
by all businesses. It will have no `result()` at all and a caller who obtains a pointer to `AbstractBusiness` with the intention of doing something with
with the thing returned by `BusinessTypeX::result()` will proceed by dynamically casting the source pointer to `BusinessTypeX *`, and calling `result()` through the target pointer only if its not null.

We still do not know what is the motivation of `AbstractBusiness`. We've just pursued the fairly plausible thought that you have "textbook" ambitions for it - Plan A - and have either failed to realize that you just haven't finished it, or you have grasped that the diversity of the data you're dealing with prevents you from finishing it per Plan A, and don't have a Plan B. Plan B is: Deepen the polymorphic hierarchy and use `dynamic_cast<LowerType *>(HigherType *)` to secure safe access to the `LowerType` interface when it outruns the `HigherType` one. <sup>[1]</sup>

The turn of Q2. now. Most likely, the reason for `Algo::result()` is simply: Because it's the done thing for a class to provide getters that directly
answer the client's natural queries, and in this case a natural query is for the *data owned by the business that is owned by the* `Algo`. But if the `Algo`  knows its business only as an `AbstractBusiness`, then it just *can't* return the data owned by its business, because the reasons already seen mean that `AbstractBusiness` can't return "the data" to the `Algo`, or to anything else.

`Algo::result()` is misconceived identically as `AbstractBusiness::result()` is misconceived. Given that `BusinessX`s data and `BusinessY`s data might need to be queried either through some repertoire of virtual methods that are still `TODO` in `AbstractBusiness` (Plan A), or perhaps through methods of `BusinessX` and `BusinessY` that are not inherited from `AbstractBusiness` at all (Plan B), the only query that `Algo` certainly can and should support with respect to its business is to return the `AbstractBusiness` pointer
through which it owns its business, leaving it to the caller to query through the pointer or downcast it, if they can, to a lower-type interface they want query.  Even if it is possible to finish `AbstractBusiness` per Plan A, the idea that the missing reportoire of methods should all be duplicated in the interface of `Algo` just so that a caller never has to receive and downcast an `AbstractBusiness` pointer is uncompelling. Would *every* type that manages an `AbstractBusiness` pointer follow suit?

Summarizing thus far, if `AbstractBusiness` has a good reason to exist, then you need either to finish it per Plan A, and work through the repercussions of so doing, or else curtail it short of attempting to be a sufficient interface for managing all businesses and bolster it with an enriched polymorphic hierarchy that clients negotiate by dynamic casting, per Plan B; and in either case you should be content for `Algo` and similar jobsworths in the `AbstractBusiness` trade just to return their `AbstractBusiness` pointer to clients who have specialized uses for it.

**Better than that, don't go there**

*But* the question of whether `AbstractBusiness` has a good reason to exist is still dangling, and should you find yourself driven to Plan B that in itself will make the question more pointed: when it transpires that an abstract interface, cast as the root class of a single inheritance hierarchy, cannot deliver Plan A then a doubt arises about the wisdom of the architecture it figures it. Dynamic casting to detect and acquire interfaces is a clunky and expensive mode of flow control and especially vexatious when - as you tell us is your situation - a scope that  will have to perform the downcasting rigmarole already knows the type it should "get out" is the type it "put in". Do all the types that are imperfectly descended from the root abstraction need to have  a single ancestor, for a reason *other* than uniformity of interface (since it doesn't give them that)?  The economies of generic interfaces are an ever-present goal, but is runtime polymorphism 
the right means, or even one of the right means, to realize them in the context of your project?

In your code-sketch, `AbstractBusiness` serves no end purpose but to furnish a
type that can uniformly fill certain slots in class `Algo`, with the effect that `Algo` can operate correctly on any type that exhibits certain traits and
behaviours. As sketched, `Algo`s only requirement of a qualifying type is
that it shall have a `result()` method that returns something: it doesn't care what. But the fact that you express `Algo`s requirements upon a qualifying type by  specifying that it shall be an `AbstractBusiness` *prohibits it* from not caring what is returned by `result()`: `AbstractBusiness` cannot do that `result()` method, although any of its descendants might do.

Suppose in that case that you sack `AbstractBusiness` from the job of enforcing the generic attributes of types on which `Algo` can operate and let `Algo` itself do that instead, by making it a template? - since it looks as if what `AbstractBusiness` is doing for `Algo` is *serving the purpose of a template parameter but sabotaging that very purpose*:

```
#include <memory>

template<class T>
class Algo {
    std::unique_ptr<T> concreteBusiness_;

public:
    explicit Algo(T * concreteBusiness)
    : concreteBusiness_{concreteBusiness}{};
    auto result() { return concreteBusiness_->result(); }
};

#include <valarray>
#include <algorithm>

struct MathBusiness {
    std::valarray<float> data_{1.1,2.2,3.3};
    float result() const { 
        return std::accumulate(std::begin(data_),std::end(data_),0.0);
    }
};

#include <string>

struct StringBusiness {
    std::string data_{"Hello World"};
    std::string result() const { return data_; }
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Algo<MathBusiness> am{new MathBusiness};
    auto ram = am.result();
    Algo<StringBusiness> as{new StringBusiness};
    auto ras = as.result();
    std::cout << ram << '\n' << ras << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

You see that in this way of transferring the genericity from `AbstractBusiness` to `Algo`, the former is left completely redundant, and so removed. This is a nutshell illustration of how the introduction of templates changed the game of C++ design root and branch, making polymporhic designs obselete for most of their prior applications to the crafting of generic interfaces.

We are working from a sketch of your problem context: perhaps there remain good reasons not in sight for `AbstractBusiness` to exist. But even if there are, they don't *per se* constitute reasons for `Algo` *not* to be a template or to have any dependency on `AbstractBusiness`. And perhaps they can one by one be eliminated by similar treatments.

Making `Algo` into a template still might not be a viable solution for you, but if it isn't then there is essentially more to the problem than we have seen. And anyhow take away this rule of thumb: Templates for generic interfaces; polymorphism for runtime adaptation of an interface's behaviour.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> What might look like another plan is to encapulate "the data" of each concrete
business in a `boost::any` or `std::experimental::any`. But you can probably
see straightaway that this is essentially the same as the idea of encapsulating
the data in a rescue abstraction, using an off-the shelf Swiss Army abstraction,
rather than crafting your own. In either guise, the idea still leaves
callers to downcast the abstraction to the type of real interest to find out
if that's what they've got, and in that sense is a variant of Plan B.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. You've given me a lot to chew on, so I'll get to it. As for your comment about not being a design problem---your point is well taken.

Comment: Well, apologies for the unusual length. Hope it at least assists you
to grapple with your problem.

Comment: Don't apologize, please. You really helped me reason about the design decisions I had made---and because of it, I'm changing my design. But your solutions aren't a waste either, I found them very informative. The `std::future` was particularly cleaver. You can tell I'm new to OO. I'm a scientific programmer from a field that considered me a rebel for being a C programmer rather than a Fortran one. I was an anarchist if I even used C with classes!  I've seen the light, and my copy of GOF just arrived last week :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to go at this. The easiest way is to not pass the ownership but call `Algo` by reference:

```
Business b;
Algo(b);
auto result = b.get_result();
```

However, sometimes this is not possible. In that case various options open up that can become quite complicated. Let me start with the most versatile and complicated one:

If you know all the types that derive from `AbstractBusiness` you could use the visitor pattern:

First we declare an abstract method `accept` in `AbstractBusiness` that takes a `BusinessVisitor`. This `visitor` will be responsible to handle the different types and perform an action based on which type it is visiting:

```
class BusinessVisitor;

struct AbstractBusiness {
  virtual ~AbstractBusiness() = default;
  virtual void accept(BusinessVisitor&) const = 0;
};
```

The `BusinessVisitor` looks like this:

```
class BusinessOne;
class BusinessTwo;

struct BusinessVisitor {
  virtual ~BusinessVisitor() = default;
  virtual void on_business_one(const BusinessOne&) {};
  virtual void on_business_two(const BusinessTwo&) {};
};
```

Some people prefer to call all methods in the visitor `visit` and let overload resolution do the rest but I prefer more explicit names.

```
struct BusinessOne {
  void accept(BusinessVisitor& v) const {
    v.on_business_one(*this);
  }
};

struct BusinessTwo {
  void accept(BusinessVisitor& v) const override {
    v.on_business_two(*this);
  }
};
```

Now we can add an `accept` method to `Algo` as well. This one will simply dispatch to the contained `AbstractBusiness` object.

```
class Algo {
  std::unique_ptr<AbstractBusiness> b_;
 public:
  Algo(std::unique_ptr<AbstractBusiness> b);
  void accept(BusinessVisitor& visitor) const override {
    return b_->accept(visitor);
  }
};
```

To get the result for a specific business type we need to define a visitor that handles this type:

```
struct BusinessOneResult : public BusinessVisitor {
  void on_business_one(const BusinessOne& b) {
    // save result;
  }

  /* ... */ get_result() const;
};
```

Now we can run `Algo` and retrieve the result:

```
auto b = std::unique_ptr<AbstractBusiness>(new BusinessOne());
Algo a(std::move(b));
BusinessOneResult visitor; 
a.accept(visitor);
auto result = visitor.get_result();
```

The real power of this approach unfolds if you don't want extract a specific value from `Algo` but if you want to trigger an action. In that case the action is usually different depending on the business type, thus the whole action can be specified in the visitor.

A different and quite elegant way would be to use a `std::future`:

```
struct Business {
  std::future</*...*/> get_future_result() {
    return promise_.get_future();
  }

  void some_method() {
    // ...
    promise_.set_value(...);
  }

 private:
  std::promise</*...*/> promise_;
};

// Must use Business here (AbstractBusiness doesn't know about the
// type of the future).
auto b = std::unique_ptr<Business>(new Business());
auto future = b.get_future_result();
Algo a(std::move(b));
auto result = future.get();
```

Another way would be to wrap the type in a class derived from a tag class (no methods or data members) and `dynamic_cast` it to the type you know it contains. Using dynamic_cast it's usually frowned upon but it has it's uses.

std::any or boost::any would be another way to go.

*Note:* I dropped the `std::move` for the argument of the `std::unique_ptr` constructor, it doesn't do a thing there: The result of the `new` operation is already an rvalue and moving a pointer is as efficient as copying it.

Comment: `Business b();` declare function `Business b()`.

Comment: Apologies for the late response. Thank you---I will work through all of this and see what fits. Right now, I'm leaning toward your very first suggestion of not even passing ownership.

Comment: @Florian I really want to thank you for your answer. I can't overstate how useful I found it. In the end, I changed my design because I realized I was trying to use polymorphism where it wasn't appropriate. I'm quite new to C++ (having been a C programmer for many years), I found your response very enlightening indeed. So much so that I printed it.

Comment: @Timtro Glad I could help. :D